# Mysql Update Query with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently try to write an sql statement based on a jointure between three tables, and i keep getting the same error. Here's my code :

`UPDATE l SET name=n.title
FROM location as l 
INNER JOIN location_instance as i
ON l.lid=i.lid 
INNER JOIN node as n 
ON n.nid = i.nid`

There are three tables in total : [location: (lid, name )] , [location_instance(nid,lid)] and [node(nid)].

Sorry if my question seems irrelevant to you, I am still a beginner in this field.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `from` clause in `update`

```
UPDATE location as l
INNER JOIN location_instance as i
ON l.lid=i.lid 
INNER JOIN node as n 
ON n.nid = i.nid
SET l.name=n.title
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this:

```
UPDATE location as l SET name=n.title 
INNER JOIN location_instance as i ON l.lid=i.lid 
INNER JOIN node as n ON n.nid = i.nid
```